# i18n translation not working with ember - Assertion Failed: Missing translation for key

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-i18n

I am using `ember-cli-i18n` in an `ember-cli` app..

I have property `menuItems` which returns..

```
[{
  text: 'leftnav_nonfollower',
  route: 'nonFollowers'
}, {
  text: 'leftnav_nonfans',
  route: 'fans'
}]
```

In template i use `menuItems` as ..

```
{{#each menuItem in navItems}}
  <li {{action 'changeRoute' menuItem }} >
    <a href="#" class='nav-circle'>
     {{t menuItem.text}}
    </a>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Now instead of looking for translation for `leftnav_nonfollower`.. the library utility `t()` is actually instead looking for translation of string `menuItem.text`.. thus giving error `Assertion Failed: Missing translation for key "menuItem.text".`

Answer (score 1):

`t` is automatically injected into Controllers, Components, Routes, and Models.

source: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-cli-i18n#utility

So, Instead of doing it in your template why don't you do it when forming the array. Something like this:

```
var menu = [{
 text: 'leftnav_nonfollower',
 route: 'nonFollowers'
}, {
  text: 'leftnav_nonfans',
  route: 'fans'
}]

menu = menu.map(function(item) {
  item.text = this.t(item.text);
  return item;
});
```

this will give you translated text in the key which you can directly use in your template.